# How to downgrade subversion 1.8 to 1.6 in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: svn

The currently installed svn version is 1.8.8 and I want to downgrade it to svn 1.6. Can you please guide me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Advantages of this answer

1. No changes in a `list` file
2. Preventing upgrades
3. Simple reversible

---

You have to download three `deb` files.

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/subversion/libsvn1_1.6.17dfsg-3ubuntu3.5_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/subversion/subversion_1.6.17dfsg-3ubuntu3.5_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/db4.8/libdb4.8_4.8.30-11ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Install via

```
sudo dpkg -i libdb4.8_4.8.30-11ubuntu1_amd64.deb\
 subversion_1.6.17dfsg-3ubuntu3.5_amd64.deb\
 libsvn1_1.6.17dfsg-3ubuntu3.5_amd64.deb
```

and prevent the upgrade

```
sudo apt-mark hold libdb4.8
sudo apt-mark hold subversion
sudo apt-mark hold libsvn1
```

---

If you want to do that later reversed.

```
sudo apt-mark unhold libdb4.8
sudo apt-mark unhold subversion
sudo apt-mark unhold libsvn1
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: @thilinistg `As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**

Comment: extract `bin/*` `x86_64-linux-gnu/*` from those `*.deb`. 
 run by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=x86_64-linux-gnu bin/svn`.
  then svn16 svn18 can coexist.